# Apache Path environment variable

Tags: windows-7, xampp

How can i configure environmental variables that are passed to apache (xampp on windows 7) and the scripts?
Is there a way to set them up in the httpd.conf?

2 Usecases:

- extending the PATH variable to be able to run the cgi-programm (dlls dependencies)
- setting some environmental variables that the programm does need during runtime

I do not want to globally set these variables

(moved to: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42064289/apache-path-environment-variable)

Comment: XAMPP is not topical here. Windows 7 is not a server OS and thus falls outside our scope too.

Comment: @istheEnglishway but there are tags for both of them and it is server related - so i do not understand your points. Sure it is not for "production" use and not meant to be online reachable - but a simple internal server based tool.

Comment: https://meta.serverfault.com/search?q=xampp

Comment: https://serverfault.com/tour

Comment: okay - thank you then i will post the question on SO

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [mod_env Apache module](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_env.html) gives you the `PassEnv` and `SetEnv` directives that enables you to set up the environment per your needs.